# how to get valid json reply in IOS application after making a webservice

Tags: php, ios

After making webservice my JSON response is as following

```
$response['success']=1;
$response['message']='enter successfully';
die(json_encode($response));
```

but when I run this in iOS application this gives me error as following

> JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

Comment: Could you post the result for `json_encode($response)`?

Comment: yes i could post result for json replay

Comment: So please edit your question with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json response is not a valid one.Please check your json object.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$response['success']=1;
$response['message']='enter successfully';
print json_encode($response);
exit();
```

Comment: same error comming by using


        header('Content-Type: application/json');
      $response['success']=1;
     $response['message']='enter successfully';
   print json_encode($response);
exit();

Comment: following is my web service

Comment: You have to put header instruction before any line codes , it must be the first !